# Switching project to new git repository

Tags: ios, xcode, git

My project A was under git source control. For my reasons, I copied project A . This copy I will called project B . So, the problem is that project B is directed to project A git repository, and I want to switch B project to new git repository. How can I do this ?

Answer (score 0):

If you mean that the remote origin references `A` (do a `git remote -v` in your repo B to be sure), you can, in command line, do a:

```
git remote set-url origin /url/of/repo/for/B
```