# Add existing git project to new repository

Tags: git, repository

I have a local git repository A, which is stored on a remote repository A'.
If I manually duplicate (copy+paste the folder containing) A so it becomes B, how can I push the content of B to a new remote repository B'? To be clear, my goal is that A and B (and A' and B' respectively) stay independent after the copy+pasting.

This is similar to a [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23027210/3976696), but here I would like to clarify whether changing the remote repository of B (e.g. using `git remote set-url origin`) will also change that of A.

My confusion comes from the fact that copy+pasting A to B leads B to automatically "know" A's remote repository, and my concern is that by changing the remote of B, it will also change that of A.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to delete the `.git/` directory in your project root folder for **B** and it will become completely independent from **A**. Then initialize it as a new repository.

You could also fork the original repository, but that wouldn't make it 100% independent as it would still have the history of **A**.

Comment: Thanks, maybe I wasn't clear enough: I want to keep the history up to the copy-paste. I don't think forking would do what I'm asking for, because I need the copy to come from the local repository, not the remote one. Is it possible to fork from the local repository?

Comment: I am honestly not sure if it's possible to do that, because the history doesn't come from the repository **B**, since it doesn't exist yet. But if you want to try, instead of deleting the `.git` folder in **B** you could try to modify its files contents (mainly the file `.git/config`) and remove all connections to repository **A** and change it to the URLs of repository **B** (that requires you to have already created it on GitHub/Bitbucket etc).